# Multiple column selection on a Julia DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, select, julia

Imagine I have the following DataFrame :

10 rows x 26 columns named A to Z

What I would like to do is to make a multiple subset of the columns by their name (not the index). For instance, assume that I want columns A to D and P to Z in a new DataFrame named df2.

I tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work :

```
df2=df[:,[:A,:D ; :P,:Z]]
```

*syntax: unexpected semicolon in array expression
top-level scope at Slicing.jl:1*

Any idea of the way to do it ?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df2 = select(df, Between(:A,:D), Between(:P,:Z))
```

or

```
df2 = df[:, All(Between(:A,:D), Between(:P,:Z))]
```

if you are sure your columns are only from `:A` to `:Z` you can also write:

```
df2 = select(df, Not(Between(:E, :O)))
```

or

```
df2 = df[:, Not(Between(:E, :O))]
```

Finally, you can easily find an index of the column using `columnindex` function, e.g.:

```
columnindex(df, :A)
```

and later use column numbers - if this is something what you would prefer.

Comment: Perfect ! Thks a lot

Answer (score 3):

In Julia you can also build `Range`s with `Char`s and hence when your columns are named just by single letters yet another option is:

```
df[:, Symbol.(vcat('A':'D', 'P':'Z'))]
```

Comment: You can also just `['A':'D'; 'P':'Z']` which is almost identical syntax to the one in the original quesion.

Comment: The syntax in the original question does not work (like the author stated in the question). It would have to be `d[:, Symbol.(['A':'D'; 'E':'F'])]` (semicolon instead of `vcat`). `d[:, ['A':'D'; 'E':'F']]` throws `ERROR: ArgumentError: idxs[1] has type Char; only Integer, Symbol, or string values allowed when indexing by vector`

Comment: this is what I have meant.